# Selecting state object name dynamically in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dynamic, state

Quick question, how do I change an object in a copy of state that is selected using e.target.name, and then set to e.target.value. Like if i want to change newState.age when e.target.name = age is sent.

```
stateUpdater = (e) => {
    const newState = this.state;
    const name = e.target.name;
    const value = e.target.value;
```

> ```
>     // How do I change newState.(name passed from target) to become the passed value;
> ```

```
    this.setState({newState});
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to update state

```
stateUpdater = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target
    this.setState({ [name]: value })
}
```